# How can I count, how many Items have been in one session together?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr, data-wrangling

I really tried my best searching through stackoverflow for a solution but unfortunatelly I couldn't find a suitable question. Therefore, I have to raise a question on my own.

I'm working with a data set containing sessionID's and topics. Imagine it looking like this:

```
sessionID <- c(1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6)
topic <- c("rock", "house", "country", "rock", "r'n'b", "pop", "classic", "house", "rock", "country")
transactions <- cbind(sessionID, topic)
transactions
```

Now, I want to find out, how many items of a certain topic have been in a session together. In the end, I want to gain a matrix, representing how often a specific topic has been in a session with the other topics. The final result should look like following:

```
topics <- sort(unique(topic))
topicPairs <- matrix(NA, nrow = length(topics), ncol = length(topics))
colnames(topicPairs) <- topics
rownames(topicPairs) <- topics
topicPairs["house", "country"] <- 2
topicPairs["country", "house"] <- 2
topicPairs["r'n'b", "pop"] <- 1
topicPairs["pop", "r'n'b"] <- 1
topicPairs["rock", "house"] <- 1
topicPairs["house", "rock"] <- 1
topicPairs["rock", "country"] <- 1
topicPairs["country", "rock"] <- 1
topicPairs["house", "house"] <- 2
topicPairs
```

For example, in row "house", column "country" should equal 2, since "house" has been together with "country" in sessions 2 and 6.

On the main diagonal I would expect, how often one topic would have been in sessions in total. Here, row "house" column "house" equals 2 since it has been in two sessions ... but I'm not sure about this.

It would be awesome, if your solution wouldn't include loops since my data set is quite big. Therefore, I would prefer functions from the tidyverse (dplyr, tidyr, etc.). Perhaps a combination of group_by and the spread function from the tidyr package.

I'm really looking for your answers. Thank you very much in advance!

Kind regards!

Comment: How about trying something like: `crossprod(table(as.data.frame(transactions)))`?

Comment: Hey Ben! Worked perfectly! Thank you so much for your quick answer! :)

Answer (score 5):

If you don't mind performing a `join` (of `transactions` to itself) via the `dplyr` package, the following should work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)

# ...
# Your existing code that created `transactions`.
# ...

# Convert transactions to a dataframe for transformation.
transactions <- as.data.frame(transactions)

result <- transactions %>%
  # Create pairings of topics by session.
  inner_join(transactions, by = "sessionID", suffix = c(".r", ".c")) %>%
  # "Pivot" the pairings, such that each topic within `topics.c` gets its own
  # column; and then aggregate the pairings by count.
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(sessionID, topic.r),
              names_from = topic.c,
              values_from = sessionID,
              values_fn = length,
              names_sort = TRUE) %>%
  # Sort appropriately, to align the main diagonal.
  arrange(topic.r) %>%
  # Convert to matrix form, with topics as row names.
  column_to_rownames(var = "topic.r") %>% as.matrix()

# View result.
result
```

Here is the printout of the `result` on my end:

```
        classic country house pop r'n'b rock
classic       1      NA    NA  NA    NA   NA
country      NA       2     2  NA    NA    1
house        NA       2     2  NA    NA    1
pop          NA      NA    NA   1     1   NA
r'n'b        NA      NA    NA   1     1   NA
rock         NA       1     1  NA    NA    3
```

## Update

The [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67824520/how-can-i-count-how-many-items-have-been-in-one-session-together#comment119885848_67824520) by [Ben](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3460670) is more elegant (not to mention cleverer), and requires only the following

```
# ...
# Your existing code that created `transactions`.
# ...

# Compute the results.
result <- crossprod(table(as.data.frame(transactions)))
# Substitute NAs for 0s, if you so desire.
result <- ifelse(result == 0, NA, result)
```

to achieve the same result.  I cannot vouch for the relative performance of either solution on large datasets.

Comment: Hey Greg! Thank you so much for your quick answer! It just works perfectly :)

Comment: My pleasure, @RKF!  If you want something more elegant, and you don't mind the twin `topic` labels showing by the row names and column names, then the solution by @Ben might be better.  You'd just need to substitute `NA` for `0` at the end (as shown in the **Update** to my answer), if you desire.

Comment: Also, thank you very much for the update. Your approach is very smart, too :) thank you for your support, I really appreciate it!