# How can I circumvent the 2^31 error thrown by the table() function?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr, data-wrangling

I really tried my best searching through stackoverflow for a solution but unfortunatelly I couldn't find a suitable question. Therefore, I have to raise a question on my own.

I'm working with a data set containing sessionID's and topics. I wanted to find out, how many items of specific topics have been purchased together. Thankfully, a stack overflow member had a great idea, using a combination of the table() function and the crossprod() function.

```
topicPairs <- crossprod(table(as.data.frame(transactions)))
```

You can look this up here: [How can I count, how many Items have been in one session together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67824520/how-can-i-count-how-many-items-have-been-in-one-session-together)

For the topics (or genres) this approach worked really well and the final matrix was really small in terms of storage usage.

However, now I want to find out, how many artists have been purchased together in different sessions. Therefore, I just replace the genres (I have 360 of them) with the artists (here, I have 35727) and apply this 'table-crossprod-combination'. Unfortunately, R throws the following error message:

```
attempt to make a table with >= 2^31 elements
```

I also understood, what happened: The table function generates one entry per session and genre. Since I only have 360 different genres, this is no problem because the number of sessions multiplied by the number of gernes is less than 2^31. On the other hand, I have 35727 different artists. If I multiply this number by the number of sessions I exceed the number of 2^31 elements.

This is actually really sad, since the solution is so smart and easy and it worked really well. Therefore, I want to ask you, if there is a way to circument this problem. Sure, my datasset is quite big ... but there are people using much bigger data sets.

Perheps, I have to split the data set up in smaller subsets and merge them together in a final step. But this is not that easy, since there are some artists which appear e.g. in subset 1 but not in subset 2. Therefore, I cannot simply add the matrices elementwise.

It would be awesome, if you could provide a solution for this problem since it drives me crazy, beeing that close to the perfect solution.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Could you do it in two stages: calculate the genre by artist counts within session and the sum over sessions?

Comment: Using the data from your previous linked question, you could try `xtabs(~ sessionID + topic, data=transactions, sparse=TRUE)` for the table stage. `Matrix` has a `crossprod` method for sparse matrices

Comment: Boom! It just works perfectly! Your solution is extremely fast and the final matrix only requires 3 MB! Thank you so much, great job! :)

Comment: @user20650 You should add (convert) your comment as (to) an answer so that OP can accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your results matrix is likely to be sparse, in that there is a high percentage of zeros, it is worth using sparse matrices to save space, if possible.

So for your [data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67824520/how-can-i-count-how-many-items-have-been-in-one-session-together):

```
sessionID <- c(1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6)
topic <- c("rock", "house", "country", "rock", "r'n'b", "pop", "classic", "house", "rock", "country")
transactions <- cbind(sessionID, topic)
```

You can use `xtabs` to return a sparse matrix (instead of the dense matrix returned by `table`), and use the `Matrix` package to find the crossproduct of this and which will retain the sparsity.

```
tab <- xtabs(~ sessionID + topic, data=transactions, sparse=TRUE)
Matrix::crossprod(tab)
```